# How to refresh a microsoft sharepoint refresh token

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-api

We have an app that needs to be able to upload an excel spreadsheet to a sharepoint drive.

Using the API I have got a token and can successfully upload this file to sharepoint.  So all things good there.

However, I have read that the refresh token only lasts 90 days and at which point I need to re-run the auth code flow to get a new refresh token.

This code that uploads the file has to be server side and can't have our clients trying to authenticate the app just to upload a file.

Is there a way that I can refresh the refresh token without going via the auth code route?

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread

Cyber security recommends these are set to expire every year, you can setup automated processes to renew the certificate.

Comment: thank you for that, unfortunately, the client won't provide us access to AD

Comment: @nzmattman Sorry for the late reply. In that case you will need to create a SharePoint app registration then https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs